# Autoprefixer errors with NPM (✖ Plugin Error: Cannot find module )

Tags: npm, autoprefixer, postcss-cli

So currently I am having troubles with autoprefixer.

I have downloaded postcss-cli and autoprefixer to --save-dev and -g

When I run a command like this:

```
postcss ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css -o ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css
```

works fine with an output of:

> ✔ Finished ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css (25ms)

Now that I have used `--use autoprefixer` an error is thrown. Command below.

```
postcss --use autoprefixer ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css -o ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css
```

Error message:

> ✖ Plugin Error: Cannot find module '../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css'

I Have tried everything and still have no solution :(

```
{
    "name": "homepage-announcements",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "Homepage announcements",
    "main": "js/Default.js",
    "dependencies": {
       "react": "^15.4.2"
     },
    "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "ava": "^0.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "postcss": "^5.2.16",
    "postcss-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "xo": "^0.18.1"
    },
    "scripts": {

    "build": "webpack -p && npm run sass && npm run css",
    "sass": "node-sass scss/default.scss ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css --output-style compressed && npm run css",
    "css": "postcss --use autoprefixer ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css -o ../../../htdocs/css/workflow/homepage-announcements.css",
    "lint": "xo js/*.js js/**/*.js js/**/**/*.js js/**/**/**/*.js js/**/**/**/**/*.js js/**/**/**/**/**/*.js"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and it turns out that the input parameters changed position.

I used to do this and it worked:

```
postcss --replace --use autoprefixer file.css
```

... But now it thinks that `file.css` is a plugin because `--use` takes an array of plugins.

You have to do this instead now:

```
postcss file.css --replace --use autoprefixer
```

Answer (score 1):

Downloading autoprefixer for cross-env worked for me :

```
npm install autoprefixer@latest cross-env --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

"prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css"

I just change the line 'prefix: css' #autoprefixer :"^9.8.5" as given in the code below and remove the -b 'last 10 version' code ,so my command runs successfully.

"prefix:css": "postcss css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css --use autoprefixer

Answer (score 0):

Add the given scripts in `package.json` file and run the script in your terminal:

```
"prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -o css/style.prefix.css css/style.concat.css"
```