# cannot find module styles.css with postcss

Tags: postcss, autoprefixer, postcss-cli

I am following this example for a quick intro to postcss:

https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-postcss/

After installing `postcss` and `autoprefixer` globally, creating a styles.css file in the root of my project and running the following command:

```
postcss -u autoprefixer styles.css -d public
```

I get the error:

```
Plugin Error: Cannot find module 'styles.css'
```

Why does it think it is is a plugin error?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue & found this related post: [Autoprefixer errors with NPM (✖ Plugin Error: Cannot find module )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227317/autoprefixer-errors-with-npm-plugin-error-cannot-find-module)

The command I ran is

```
postcss styles.css -d dist -u autoprefixer
```

As the related answer shows, -u now takes multiple plugins so the order has to be modified.

Also if you use that tutorial, the example of "display: flex;" is no longer useful as it will work "as is" across browsers. Instead use

```
::placeholder {
  color: gray;
}
```

to test autoprefixer

Comment: how can I run this command but replace current css file with new, in a project with 100ds of .css files? I tried this:
`npx postcss ./src/**/*.css -d dist -u autoprefixer`